# Automatically adding table row via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to add a table row dynamically via jQuery. Everything works fine but the row just won't add itself to the last < tr>. Instead, it adds itself above the < table>...

I am quite confused. Could anyone help me out? Here is the code

**Javascript**

```
var counterx = 2;
var counter = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addMoreRcpt").click(function(){
        if (counterx>10){
            alert("Only 10 reciepients are allowed");
            return false;
        }

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'RcptEml_' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.append("<tr><td>New Data</td><td>New Data</td><td>New Data</td></tr>");

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#RcptGroup");
        counter++;
        counterx++;
    });
});

function fncDelRcpt(id){
    $("#RcptEml_"+id).remove();
    counterx--;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border=1>
<div id="RcptGroup">
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
</tr>
<div id="1">
<tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>data</td>
</tr>
</div>
</div>

</table>
<br /><a id="addMoreRcpt" href="#" >Add more reciepients</a>
```

Comment: You're wrapping `tr` elements within a `div` within a `table`? That's invalid HTML and may be the cause of your problems. A `div` can appear inside of a `th` or `td`, but *nowhere else* within a `table`.

Comment: Your code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/2au73/ @DavidThomas is perhaps right, at least heed his advice.

Comment: Yes and obviously jQuery's append() creates tbody tag and appends new rows in it, while your other rows are left still directly inside the table. If you don't want to use that tbody, use basic javascript also here: `document.getElementById('RcptGroup').appendChild(newTextBoxDiv[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's changed parts of your code that should work:

**The Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addMoreRcpt").click(function() {
        if (counterx > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 reciepients are allowed");
            return false;
        }
        var newTextBoxRow = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id", 'RcptEml_' + counter);
        newTextBoxRow.append("<td>New Data</td><td>New Data</td><td>New Data</td>");
        newTextBoxRow.appendTo("#RcptGroup");
        counter++;
        counterx++;
    });
});​
```

**The Table:**

```
<table border="1" id="RcptGroup">
    <tr id="0">
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="RcptEml_1">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

---

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/2au73/5/

---

As suggested in the comments to your question, `<Div/>`s cannot be nested within `<Table/>`s. Here's a guideline for `HTML 4.01`, but almost all of it should still hold true: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nesting.html

Comment: Here's the rub: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/2au73/2/ Where's the `click`able element?

Comment: @JaredFarrish the answer did suggest that it contained only changed parts. But I have added a fiddle for clarity. :)

Comment: Hi thanks! this works great! could you also please tell me how i can add a class to the dynamically added tr? As in

    var newTextBoxRow = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id", 'RcptEml_' + counter);

I would like to add the class "test" here too

Comment: `newTextBoxRow.addClass("classname");`

Comment: You are just awesome! Thanks bPatrik and all others who helped me out!